How can i pass the instance of current activity also get the same instance in my next activity?
val intent = Intent(this@AppScreenActivity,ProfileActivity::class.java)
             val activityObject = ActivityObject(this::class.java.name)
             intent.putExtra("Activity",activityObject)
             startActivity(intent)

@Parcelize
data class ActivityObject(
    val activityClassName: String? = null
):Parcelable

val temp=intent.getParcelableExtra<ActivityObject>("Activity")
activitys=Class.forName(temp?.activityClassName!!).newInstance() as? AppCompatActivity

i tried this but not getting the same instance
